# Options available for calling into a workbook addin

Tags: excel, vba

-First- what i have currently is one workbook- lets call it WBK. That workbook, WBK via a button, and hence on demand, uses VBIDE.Project to load a reference to a xlam (excel addin). When done- i can look at Tools  -> References and see that a new reference to the  xlam is created.

So far so good.

WBK can even refer to the xlam and call public Sub(routines) on it, via the xlam project name. So if the xlam addin project name is *Stack* , i am able to have a module (lets call it M) in WBK call:
Call Stack.CallMe
where CallMe is a function defined in a module in the xlam  addin.

However - on certain PCs i've noticed that excel tries to compile the module M when the Workbook WBK opens and fails to resolve *Stack* because - the addin is not loaded as yet.

Is there a way to control this compile behavior?
Is there another way to call into a addin perhaps using late binding ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem... Would you would like your WBK to be able calling functions from a not installed add-in? When  WBK is open, it checks its references and if you will verify them you will see a `missing` one. Then, why do not make your add-in able to create a new Ribbon Tab and offer, in this way, to all open workbooks, all the necessary functions to be run without any reference...

Comment: Sort of- I would like to install the xlam as a reference. When done- youll see the xlam *Sheet* under Tools -> References. This works. Now you can use that reference- like, Sheet.CallMe() to call a function on the xlam. That also works. But the problem is that if you try compiling your module in WBK that contains the Stack.CallMe() line before youve actually added the Stack reference to Tools->References, you get a compile error. So i was wondering if there is a way to use late binding to get a handle to a xlam reference ?

Comment: Sorry... I miss-read your question. If your Excel session is starting by that specific WBK, it may happen what you tells us. But you can handle the issue in a different way. One way would be to to what I suggested above (your add-in will create a new Ribbon Tab and offers, in this way, access to its subs/functions for all open workbooks) and the second one would be to call the add-in functions/subs, without referencing it, in this way: `Application.Run "YourAddInName.xlam!testMsgbox"`...

Comment: I will certainly try ribbon tab access. Can you get a reference to a ribbon tab dynamically ? As for Application.Run i was hoping to avoid going down that route- unless i had to mostly out of concerns around performance. The Stack.CallMe i.e. using a direct reference is ideal- except for the missing reference error.

Comment: I am driving now. I will be home after 6 to 7 hours... i posted recently a solution amle to create a hyperlynk and the necessary event and also, how to create a Ribbon Tab. But not automatically, which I considsr being unnecessary, since you must xistribute your add-In...